# Display waiting image while exporting to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
 <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
<ProgressTemplate>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="waiting.gif" AlternateText="Processing" runat="server" />
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn_PDF" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/pdf.png" Width="34" Height="17" Style="padding-top: 7px"  OnClick="imgBtn_PDF_Click"   />
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
 <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgBtn_PDF" />
 </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>  

In the above code am using the update panel i am displaying waiting message with progress bar while exporting to PDF.The image is displayed when i use the trigger as asynchronous postback but am not able to export to PDF.But when use postbacktrigger am not able to display the waiting message.Below is my codebehind code to export to excel  

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(pdfFile));
                sourceFile = new FileStream(pdfFile, FileMode.Open);
                long FileSize;
                FileSize = sourceFile.Length;
                byte[] getContent = new byte[(int)FileSize];
                sourceFile.Read(getContent, 0, (int)sourceFile.Length);
                sourceFile.Close();
                Response.BinaryWrite(getContent);
```

In the above code am adding a header of type PDF,opening the file in open mode and storing the content in getContent of bytes then reading the whole file through bytes and exporting throgh BinaryWrite

Comment: I have asked a question but i had not got any reply from 4 days please help its urgent.